# List local printers

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am using this routine to list the local printers installed on a machine:

```
var
  p: pointer;
  hpi: _PRINTER_INFO_2A;
  hGlobal: cardinal;
  dwNeeded, dwReturned: DWORD;
  bFlag: boolean;
  i: dword;
begin
  p := nil;
  EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, nil, 2, p, 0, dwNeeded, dwReturned);
  if (dwNeeded = 0) then exit;
  GetMem(p,dwNeeded);
  if (p = nil) then exit;
  bFlag := EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, nil, 2, p, dwneeded, dwNeeded, dwReturned);
  if (not bFlag) then exit;
  CbLblPrinterPath.Properties.Items.Clear;
  for i := 0 to dwReturned - 1 do
  begin
    CbLblPrinterPath.Properties.Items.Add(TPrinterInfos(p^)[i].pPrinterName);
  end;
  FreeMem(p);
```

---

`TPrinterInfos(p^)[i].pPrinterName` returns a 'P' for printer name. I have a PdfCreator installed as a printer.

`TPrinterInfos` is an array of `_PRINTER_INFO_2A`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, first thing first...  Since you tagged this Delphi-2010, I'd assume you are having this problem with D2010.

Your problem start with your use of _PRINTER_INFO_2A, which is the structure used by the Ansi version of the function EnumPrinters.  Ever since unicode has been introduced, the "EnumPrinters" function maps to the unicode version of the function, and thus, you should use _PRINTER_INFO_2W. (Or explicitly call EnumPrintersA).  If you are using EnumPrinters(Without A/W) you should use the _PRINTER_INFO_2(without A/W). That way, it will be less likely to break if one day a UTF32 version becomes the new standard.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a list of Local Printers by Simply using the list provided in the Printer variable.   Simple as

```
uses Printers;
...
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Assign(Printer.Printers);
end;
```

I would use this method unless you have a specific reason for doing what you are doing.

More recently I have created a github repo with a utility that does this.

[github.com/tobya/listprn](https://github.com/tobya/listprn)

Comment: Printer.Printers doesn't give the local printers only.

Comment: @Remko One can execute the following statement to refresh the list of printers: 
    Printer.Refresh;

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using unicode Delphi version you should use _PRINTER_INFO_2W structure instead of _PRINTER_INFO_2A